# Equivalent of GREATEST() in HQL

Tags: mysql, hql

I'm trying to find the greatest of two dates in HQL.

In SQL this works:

```
SELECT ( GREATEST(a1.startDate, '2019-10-01T00:00:00Z') ) FROM Activity AS a1 WHERE a1.id = 66232
```

But the equivalent in HQL gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'GREATEST' {originalText=GREATEST}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       +-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=param0, expectedType=null}
       \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=param1, expectedType=null}
 [SELECT GREATEST(:param0,:param1) FROM xxx.xxx.xxx.Activity AS a1 WHERE a1.id = :param2]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
    ... 134 more
```

Is there a way to achieve the same thing as MySQL's GREATEST() with two dates in HQL?

EDIT: I also tried using CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END but ended up wiht the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SearchedCaseNode 
 \-[CASE] SearchedCaseNode: 'CASE'
    +-[WHEN] SqlNode: 'WHEN'
    |  +-[GT] BinaryLogicOperatorNode: '>'
    |  |  +-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=param0, expectedType=null}
    |  |  \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=param1, expectedType=null}
    |  \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=param2, expectedType=null}
    \-[ELSE] SqlNode: 'ELSE'
       \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=param3, expectedType=null}
 [SELECT CASE WHEN :param0 > :param1 THEN :param2 ELSE :param3 END  FROM flowzone.model.activity.Activity AS a1 WHERE a1.id = :param4]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
    ... 138 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL manual explains `GREATEST()` as

> `GREATEST(value1,value2,...)`
>
> With two or more arguments, returns the largest (maximum-valued)
>   argument.

So MySQL's `GREATEST(value1,value2,...)` function/syntax sugar should be the same as the MySQL syntax below..

```
SELECT 
 MAX(greatest.v)
FROM (
  SELECT value1 AS v
  UNION ALL
  SELECT value2 AS v
  [, UNION ALL SELECT ...]
) AS greatest
```

Not sure if it is HQL proof, but maybe the query below?

```
SELECT 
 MAX(alias.startDate)
FROM (
  SELECT a1.startDate FROM Activity AS a1 WHERE a1.id = 66232
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CAST('2019-10-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS startDate
) AS alias
```